# ubuntu 15.04 cursor not showing after up-gradation

Tags: updates

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 and after successful up-gradation, neither trackpad nor mouse cursor is showing.

Comment: I have an old HP Pavillion running 16.04. When waking up after suspend the cursor can be "anything", like random values in the cursor matrix, sometimes only a few pixels of the cursor showing etc. I solve it by moving the (often invisible) cursor to the activity bar and and when the cursor is over f.ex Chromium (hover over the icon will show text) I click it and Chromium will set a good cursor and problem is solved. // I just report this here since there are people reading this who know well if this is a bug to be reported.